# User exit EXIT_SAPLV54B_002 is not called

Tags: abap, function-module

In SAP ABAP function module `SD_SCD_PRICING_PREPARE` is called when creating a shipment cost doc by tcode `VI01`.

There is a user exit `EXIT_SAPLV54B_002` which should be used to include additional fields in pricing.

The exit is activated by activating the include `ZXV54U03` and writing the required logic. However, I placed a break point in the include to check if the program will call the exit but it does not.

[image]

With the break point in include ZXV54U03, the system should have stopped when creating a shipment cost document via VI01 but this doesn't happen. Please advice.

Comment: Actually activation of the include should be enough. Try to set the breakpoint not in include itself, but inside the function EXIT_SAPLV54B_002 or even earlier in FM SD_SCD_PRICING_PREPARE to debug what is going on. Maybe in your business case it would not be called at all because of other conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks all
exit needed activation through SMOD & CMOD

Answer (score 0):

From this description, two possibilities came to my mind.

My first question is, are you sure this USEREXIT will start? I am not sure if the code will make it this far.
Put the debug point in the EXIT_SAPLV54B_002 code or in the SD_SCD_PRICING_PREPARE function module and try to get to that point.

Another idea is to turn on the System Debugging option.
In debug mode you can find it under the settings tab. If you turn this on and press Continue(F8), it should stop there.

[image]

Comment: thanks all
exit needed activation through SMOD & CMOD.